# Chrome console toggling devices for CSS edit

Tags: html, css

I open my console, I go to toggling devices(on top left of the console), then in the middle of the page, there are options for to me pick (iphone/galaxys) which would fit the screen, but I want to develop my stuff for 15 and 13 inches of computer devices, I am on a 17 inch device, how do I achieve that?

Comment: Whoever downvoted can you at least provide me with an answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The idea you're developing for a certain 'size' of device is a common mistake when starting with responsive design. Instead of physical size, what you're really developing for is resolution.

When you select the iPhone or Galaxy option from the dropdown you'll notice it pre-populates the height and width inputs:

[image]

[image]

So, if you want to design for 13" or 15" device, what you really want to know is the resolution of the device. For example, the current 13.3" Macbook Pro has a resolution of 2560-by-1600 pixels. While a Dell XPS 13" with QHD Display has a resolution of 3200-by-1800 pixels.

To design for the standard 13" to 15" sizes, you'll want to set the option to `Responsive`, then set the resolution to 2560-by-1600, or in that ballpark.

[image]

Also, in the `Responsive` mode, you can simply drag the right-side and bottom-side to resize the window. This makes it possible to see how your site will appear on a range of resolutions really quickly.

PS - I didn't downvote

Comment: Wait I am confused, how do I implement this in css? all the desktops will have the same view anyways? Is there like a few lines of code which would save from all that work, setting pixels for each?

Comment: The answer to that is beyond the scope of this question. One approach is to target resolution ranges, like all devices with a resolution less than 640 pixels in width. Then all devices 641 to X1, X1 +1 to X2, and so on, then finally all resolutions greater than XN. The targeting is accomplished using media queries in your CSS.